# How to log a process's uptime and restarts

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, ps, ffmpeg

I know that I can check a process's uptime with the following:

```
ps -o etime= -p "PID"
```

where PID = pid number.

I would like to write to a log when this process ends, and include it's uptime.  The exact time it exits would be nice, but not strictly necessary.  I have a script which automatically restarts it, but I am looking to increase it's stability.  In this case, the process is ffmpeg.  I am running a very low bandwidth stream from an unstable source, and the process frequently, intermittently fails.

I feel that if I could log it for a day or two, I could try different configurations to see if I can extend the uptime to an acceptable limit.

Thank you for your valuable insight!

Comment: Add `-benchmark` to the ffmpeg cmd. Upon exit, ffmpeg will print, among other things, rtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,time,args
```

This command lists all processes with several different time-related columns. pipe it to `grep ffmpeg` to find out about the your process of interest.

The output of the previous command has the following columns:

```
PID COMMAND                          STARTED     ELAPSED     TIME COMMAND
```

according to [ps man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)

```
PID = Process ID
first COMMAND = only the command name without options and without arguments
STARTED = the absolute time the process was started
ELAPSED = elapsed time since the process was started (wall clock time), format [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss TIME = cumulative CPU time, "[dd-]hh:mm:ss" format
second COMMAND = again the command, this time with all its provided options and arguments
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I ended up creating a log file and appending to it within my restart script.  The script time stamps the restart event.  I can now calculate uptime by subtracting the difference between restart events.  I run the restart script every minute with crontab.  (The script only executes a restart and writes to the log if ffmpeg is not running.)